# Facebook can't finish()

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I have a problem. I want when I log in from my MainActivity to go to another activity, which I already did, but at the same time I don't want to be able to go back, and the logout button become in MainActivity2.

**Code:**

```
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

        Intent mainLobby = new Intent (getActivity(), MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(mainLobby);
        if(!isMainLobbyStarted) {
            startActivity(mainLobby);
            isMainLobbyStarted = true;

            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Bem-vindo " + profile.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you not to go back to activity 1, you can override the onBackPressed() on activity 2 to do nothing.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    //do nothing
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But you know who i can "move" the buton?

Comment: i am sorry, can you explain what do you mean by moving the button?

Comment: When I login move the login button to the secound activity

Comment: Why would you want a login button on the second activity once you have already logged in? You could simply have the logout button on the second activity

Comment: Yes i want a Logout Button on the second activity... but i dont know how to do it